# How do I validate input without exiting my do while loop?

Tags: c++, validation, loops, input, do-while

I'm working on a program that prompts the user to select from 3 different options by inputing an integer from 1-3 (4 to quit). I need to write a code that validates that the input is an integer, and reprompts them if it is not an integer. Here's the basic idea of my code (it is too long to post in entirety).

```
do 
{
cout << "Menu: Please select one of the following options:" << endl;
    cout << " 1 - Drop a single chip into one slot." << endl;
    cout << " 2 - Drop multiple chips into one slot." << endl;
    cout << " 3 - Drop 5 chips into each slot." << endl;
    cout << " 4 - Quit the program." << endl;
    cout << "Enter your selection now: ";
    cin >> first_input;
}while (first_input!=4)
```

I then have multiple if statements that execute expressions based on which option the user chooses. I also prompt them to enter other integer values later in the code.

How do I send the user back to the menu, if the user inputs fails to input an integer and instead inputs characters? Constraints: Cannot use `continue` or `break`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go back to the start in case of non-integer input, perhaps something like this would work?

```
// Insert after "cin >> first_input;"
if (cin.fail()) {
    // Handle non-int value.

    // Clear error flag.
    cin.clear();

    // Empty buffer up to next newline.
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    // Complain & restart.
    cout << "Invalid input.  Please try again." << endl;
    continue;
}
```

What this does is clear the error flag, purge the buffer, and go back to the start.  `cin.ignore()` doesn't explicitly need to be passed `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` as its first parameter; however, in case of error, I prefer to do so to make sure that the erroneous input is gone.  Note that `std::numeric_limits` is defined in the standard header `<limits>`, and requires its inclusion.

Comment: Thank you! Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`continue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue) keyword.

Comment: Thank you for responding quickly. Is there another way? While I'm positive that would solve it, I am required to not use `continue`.

Comment: @T.Rydalch: Required by what or whom? If you have arbitrary contraints on which pieces of C++ you're "allowed" to use, I'd appreciate it if you'd state that up-front in the question next time instead of waiting until we've already written an answer....

Comment: Duly noted. My Course Instructor.

Comment: @T.Rydalch: So this is a school assignment. Presumably the intention is for you to come up with the idea yourself! Not to get someone on the internet to do it for you...

Comment: to my understanding, stackoverflow.com is a place to ask programming questions and receive answers that enable you to continue learning. My instructor has no issue with us using stackoverflow, but I appreciate your concern.

Comment: Consider nested loops.

Comment: @Alectris: Add your constraints to the question. Several other people have now also spent time posting answers that use `continue`, because you did not specify in the question that you are unable to use `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
do 
{
    cout << "Menu: Please select one of the following options:" << endl;
    cout << " 1 - Drop a single chip into one slot." << endl;
    cout << " 2 - Drop multiple chips into one slot." << endl;
    cout << " 3 - Drop 5 chips into each slot." << endl;
    cout << " 4 - Quit the program." << endl;
    cout << "Enter your selection now: ";
    cin >> first_input;
    //lets say if user enters value out of range. then want to show menu again.
    if(first_input > 4) {
        cout << "Invalid input "<<endl;
        continue;
    }
    // you can do other stuff here. 
    // ...
}while (first_input!=4)
```

Comment: This doesn't address OP's problem "*How do I send the user back to the menu, if the user inputs fails to input an integer and instead inputs characters?*"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ***goto label.***

```
do{
   label:
        // your code
if(check) goto label;
}while(check);
```